# Run after_rollback callback for rollbacks due to another callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to raise a dummy exception while doing 'save'(while creating) and see if the method in `after_rollback` callback works fine.

I'm doing something like this:

```
before_create :do_something
after_create :raise_exception
after_rollback :revert_method
```

Here, rollback is happening, but revert_method in `after_rollback` isn't executed.

(I want the before_create callbacks to run as well, so cannot raise the exception before that.)

Comment: `after_rollback` isn't executed in tests, right?

Comment: By testing, I meant verifying if the code works properly. Not the rails tests. Changed the question, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a debugger like the **[Byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug)** gem to follow and inspect the flow of your application step by step.

See Rails Guides section [Debugging with the byebug gem](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-byebug-gem)

Comment: My question was how to check the working of 'revert_method' by throwing an exception explicitly. The problem is I'm not able to trigger the after_rollback callback method.

Comment: my question is that like when after_rollback callback runs